# CSS Animations with Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, animation

I am trying to get a little slide show going on a landing page.  It works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome.
[Example Page](http://certs.vwsvandalia.com/test/html/test.html)
Here is my CSS

```
/*
    ********* The Slide Show.  Weeeeeee! *********
*/

/* SLIDER STRUCTURE */

#slider {
   background: #000;
   border: 5px solid #eaeaea;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   height: 320px;
   width: 680px;
   margin: 40px auto 0;
   overflow: visible;
   position: relative;
}

/* HIDE ALL OUTSIDE OF THE SLIDER */

#mask {
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 320px; 
}

/* IMAGE LIST */

#slider ul {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: relative;
}

#slider li { 
   width: 680px;  /* Width Image */
   height: 320px; /* Height Image */
   position: absolute;
   top: -325px; /* Original Position - Outside of the Slider */
   list-style: none;
}

#slider li.firstanimation {
   animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;   
}

#slider li.secondanimation {
   animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;
}

#slider li.thirdanimation {
   animation: cyclethree 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;       
}

#slider li.fourthanimation {
   animation: cyclefour 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;        
}

#slider li.fifthanimation {
   animation: cyclefive 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: cycle 25s linear infinite;        
}

/* ANIMATION */

@keyframes cycle {
   0%  { top: 0px; } /* When you start the slide, the first image is already visible */
   4%  { top: 0px; } /* Original Position */
   16% { top: 0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } /* From 4% to 16 % = for 3 seconds the image is visible */
   20% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; } /* From 16% to 20% = for 1 second exit image */
   21% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; } /* Return to Original Position */
   92% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   96% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; } /* From 96% to 100% = for 1 second enter image*/
   100%{ top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes cycletwo {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; } /* Original Position */
   16% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }/* Starts moving after 16% to this position */
   20% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   24% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }  /* From 20% to 24% = for 1 second enter image*/
   36% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }   /* From 24% to 36 % = for 3 seconds the image is visible */
   40% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; } /* From 36% to 40% = for 1 second exit image */
   41% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }   /* Return to Original Position */
   100%{ top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}

@keyframes cyclethree {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   36% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   40% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   44% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; } 
   56% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; } 
   60% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   61% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; } 
   100%{ top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}

@keyframes cyclefour {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   56% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   60% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   64% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   76% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
   80% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   81% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
   100%{ top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}

@keyframes cyclefive {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   76% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   80% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   84% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   96% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
   100%{ top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
}

/* For Chrome + Safari + Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
   0%  { top: 0px; } /* When you start the slide, the first image is already visible */
   4%  { top: 0px; } /* Original Position */
   16% { top: 0px; opacity:1; z-index:0; } /* From 4% to 16 % = for 3 seconds the image is visible */
   20% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; } /* From 16% to 20% = for 1 second exit image */
   21% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; } /* Return to Original Position */
   92% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   96% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; } /* From 96% to 100% = for 1 second enter image*/
   100%{ top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cycletwo {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; } /* Original Position */
   16% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }/* Starts moving after 16% to this position */
   20% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   24% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }  /* From 20% to 24% = for 1 second enter image*/
   36% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }   /* From 24% to 36 % = for 3 seconds the image is visible */
   40% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; } /* From 36% to 40% = for 1 second exit image */
   41% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }   /* Return to Original Position */
   100%{ top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cyclethree {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   36% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   40% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   44% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; } 
   56% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; } 
   60% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   61% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; } 
   100%{ top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cyclefour {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   56% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   60% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   64% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   76% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
   80% { top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
   81% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
   100%{ top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cyclefive {
   0%  { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   76% { top: -325px; opacity: 0; }
   80% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   84% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; }
   96% { top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 0; }
   100%{ top: 325px; opacity: 0; z-index: 0; }
}

/* Welcome Text-area formatting stuffs */
#welcome-text
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 700px;
    text-align: left;
}

#small-print
{
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I have been Google'ing for a while and trying a few things out, but I just can't quite figure it out.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Nathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply missed your cycle names:

```
#slider li.secondanimation {
   animation: cycletwo 25s linear infinite;
   -webkit-animation: ***cycle*** 25s linear infinite; // change to cycletwo
}
```

and so on.